# How does the RC component of a organic photodiode impact the response speed?

Tags: resistance, solar-cell, capacitance, photodiode, photonics

As I hate abstractions, I'm trying to understand at the physical level how capacitance forms within photodiode and how it decreases the performance with resistance.

Comment: What does an LED have to do with a solar cell?

Comment: What R and what C inside a solar cell? ESR as in equivalent series resistance?

Comment: @JRE edited the title. LED is also impacted also by RC however I do understand that but in the solar cell it puzzles me.

Comment: @winny yes. Resistance Capacitance

Comment: Yes is not an answer as to what. Please draw a schematic.

Comment: @Neil_UK i'm trying to use them as receiver for VLC. I should rename it actually as Photodiode even tough their working principle is the same.

Comment: Electronics Engineering is **pretty much all about** abstractions. If you hate them try physics.se

Comment: First it was LED, then solar panel and now photodiode. What's next?

Comment: @winny working principle of photodiode and solar panel are same. wideband absorbtion is key for solar cell while narrowband is key for photodiode but essentially they are the same thing. only the purpose and materials are different.

Comment: Oh! Next was _organic_ photodiode. The saga continues. What's next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A photodiode in the dark is just a diode.  If you reverse bias it, the PN junction acts as an insulator - it doesn't allow current to flow.  The PN junction has two wires going into it.

Pretty much by definition, two conductors with an insulator between is a capacitor.

If you shine a light on the photodiode, it starts to conduct.  The capacitor turns into a leaky capacitor.

---

As for the RC bit.  If you put a resistor in series with a capacitor when charging or discharging it, less current flows, the time to charge increases, and the dV/dt (rate of change of voltage) goes down.  Practical photodiode circuits are likely to have resistors in them to keep the diode reverse biased.

If the resistor is too high, and you're trying to transmit high bandwidth data, then the voltage won't change quick enough.

Comment: RC time constant is basically product of this series resistor and capacitance? and as amount of charge increases in the diode, it takes more time to discharge. is it how it impacts the response speed?

Comment: @LifeIsBeatiful If your time constant is longer than the time period between your data bits, then the charge won't have a chance to build up again between bits, so the data will be lost.  You need to make sure the time constant is shorter than the time between data pulses.